# Navigate to other tab in bottom navigation bar from HomeView?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a bottom navigation bar like this:
[image]

When i click (1) in tab Home, it navigate to Detail page of item in tab My Learning (2) but not tab My Learning (using Navigator.of(context).push()). But not change tab to My Learning in bottom navigation bar, it still tab Home. So how i fix that. Thank you.

Some code:
Class main_view_model (contain bottom navigation bar):

```
  BottomTabItemAfterSignIn _currentBottomTab = BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.home;

  BottomTabItemAfterSignIn get currentBottomTab => _currentBottomTab;

  void changeTab(BottomTabItemAfterSignIn tab, {bool isBackClick = false}) {
    if (_currentBottomTab != tab) {
      _currentBottomTab = tab;
    }
  }
```

Class main_view:

```
  @override
  Widget buildView(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        _onPressBackDevice();

        return false;
      },
      child: Selector<MainUserViewModel, BottomTabItemAfterSignIn>(
        selector: (_, viewModel) => viewModel.currentBottomTab,
        builder: (_, currentBottomTab, __) {
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: AppColor.neutrals.shade900,
            body: _buildBody(),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationUserWidget(
              currentTab: currentBottomTab,
              onSelectTab: _selectTab,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    if (viewModel.currentBottomTab == BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.home) {
      return _buildTabItem(
        BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.home,
        _cacheBottomTabWidgets[BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.home],
      );
    } else if (viewModel.currentBottomTab == BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.course) {
      return _buildTabItem(
        BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.course,
        _cacheBottomTabWidgets[BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.course],
      );
    } else if (viewModel.currentBottomTab ==
        BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.myLearning) {
      return _buildTabItem(
        BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.myLearning,
        _cacheBottomTabWidgets[BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.myLearning],
      );
    } else {
      return _buildTabItem(
        BottomTabItemAfterSignIn.setting,
        _cacheBottomTabWidgets[BottomTabItemBeforeSignIn.setting],
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _buildTabItem(BottomTabItemAfterSignIn tabItem, Widget? child) {
    // Cache Widget
    return Offstage(
      offstage: viewModel.currentBottomTab != tabItem,
      child: child ??
          (viewModel.currentBottomTab == tabItem
              ? _buildCacheTab(tabItem)
              : Container()),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCacheTab(BottomTabItemAfterSignIn tabItem) {
    return _cacheBottomTabWidgets[tabItem] =
        BottomBodyNavigationUserWidget(
      bottomMenuBar: tabItem,
      navigatorKey: _bottomTabKeys[tabItem]!,
    );
  }

  void _selectTab(BottomTabItemAfterSignIn bottomMenuBar) {
    viewModel.changeTab(bottomMenuBar);
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure this kind of scenario is possible in Android native and flutter development. Please double check the official guide https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#connect, and how to connect it with ```BottomNavigationView```.

Comment: just to make sure we are on the same page in understanding each other. I did a similar scenario on ```kotlin```, but things how you did in ```flutter``` is different. That's a point of my concerns and that's why I advise to double check it in official docs and android samples.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using stateful widget if so then you have to use `setState((){})` to to effect any value change so your code for `_currentBottomTab = tab;` should like this:

```dart
    setState((){
        _currentBottomTab = tab;
    });
```

For more info on stateful widget please check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).

Comment: Nope, when i tap in bottom navigation, it still change tab. But when i tap (1). It push to new view (page detail of my learning), but not change tab.

Answer (score 0):

use the same fun on 1-tab nd pass the index number where you want to go

```
changeTab(2),
```

Comment: Nope, when i using changeTab(2), it navigate to tab My learning (Page my learning), but not push to page detail of my learning.

Comment: Do you have some more details to show against that option??? and you want to show on other page ??

Comment: yeah, detail of item (1), but this item is detail of my learning page

Comment: call the details page directly form on tap fun

Comment: I don't get what you mean

Comment: I mean call the page you want directly for on tap fun  it will navigate on the same